# Prevent checking in project files

Tags: visual-studio, t4, ankhsvn

I am trying to prevent ankhsvn from checking in the app.config files in my projects. A bit of background.

I like to generate my app.config and not check them in to source control because in my experience each developer likes to keep a different version of it (so that for a multi-tier system, they can point to their own dev system).

However I still want the file in my project, just not in source control. However Ankh seems to get it in its head that means I must want to check it in. Is there someway to globally (scoped to that file, but across ALL users and ALL branches) prevent Ankh from checking in this one file?

Comment: Usually, in Subversion I use ignore pattern for this. For ankh [check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4223144/540345) it might be helpful.

Comment: can you check in an ignore rule. I've seen lots of per user per repository solutions. But these don't stop my colleagues from checking in and creating merge issues where none exist.

Comment: ya..I did not see any straight forward way for this. In our project, we created a file called `SVN Ignore Patterns.txt` and included that file in source control. Each time when a person adds new pattern to the file, everyone else updates there svn settings manually. This requires good understanding b/w the team members!

Comment: Sigh...I like to treat all my colleagues like idiots, simply because if I don't, the idiot that makes the mistake is me. IMHO this should be fixed by the SVN peoples.